# ngif if is false go to loop

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to check the filename variable if has value but if the value is null is trying to execute the ngfor

```
<h2>{{news.content}}</h2>


<ng-container *ngIf="filename">
    <div *ngFor="let file of filename">
        <img src="{{'http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/'+file}}"  style = "width: auto;margin: auto;display: block;">
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: And what's the issue ... ? Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: isn't it just `!filename`? Since `filename` is a string

Comment: @Huangism yes true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
*ngIf="filename.length!==0"
```

Comment: Or *ngIf="filename.length"

Comment: when I get null value I get the following error Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Answer (score 2):

Check the filename length.

```
*ngIf="filename?.length > 0"
```

Comment: that will crash if filename is <string>

Answer (score 0):

To cast any value to boolean and make a secure check, please use double negation operator, like this:

```
*ngIf="!!filename"
```

This way,

```
if true -> false -> true
if 25 -> false -> true
if "Hello world" -> false -> true
if null -> true -> false
if undefined -> true -> false
if false -> true -> false
```